# tazpkg install option asking for su when in chrooted image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chroot

I am trying to install a couple of packages in slitaz chrootd image but
tazpkg keeps asking for su privilages. 
I have fallowed this tutorial http://doc.slitaz.org/en:handbook:chroot

Host is Ubuntu 11.10 .